# Java generics: collection of super of super of some type

Tags: java, generics, superclass, super

Consider the following self-contained sample:

```
import java.util.*;

class TestApplication
{

interface Type<C>
{
    Collection<Type<? super C>> getSuperTypes();
}

static class Test<C>
{
    private final Type<? super C> mySuperType = get( null );

    public Collection<Type<? super C>> getSuperTypes()
    {
        Collection<Type<? super C>> superTypes = new ArrayList<>();
        superTypes.add( mySuperType );

        //directly passing the super-types to addAll() works
        superTypes.addAll( mySuperType.getSuperTypes() );

        //but how can I declare the variable to temporarily hold the supers?
        Collection<Type<? super C>> superSuperTypes = mySuperType.getSuperTypes(); //ERROR
        superTypes.addAll( superSuperTypes );

        return superTypes;
    }
}

public static <T> T get( T value )
{
    return value;
}

}
```

So, I have this class which represents a type, and it has a super-type which in turn has super-types, and I want to have a function which returns a flat collection of all super-types of a type.

So, I declare a collection of super-types and I add to it the immediate super-type of the current type, and then I need to also add the super-types of the super-type.  (Never mind that it is horrendously inefficient, in reality I do it in a much more efficient way, but that's irrelevant.)

So, the goal is to invoke `superTypes.addAll()` passing it the result of `superType.getSuperTypes()`.

When the result of `superType.getSuperTypes()` gets directly passed to `superTypes.addAll()` without an intermediate variable, there is no problem.

But if I want to declare an intermediate variable `superSuperTypes` to hold the result of `superType.getSuperTypes()` before passing it to `superTypes.addAll()`, I cannot find a way to declare that variable so that it will compile.  As it stands, it gives the following message:

`Error:(100, 84) java: incompatible types:  java.util.Collection<TestApplication.Type<? super capture#1 of ? super C>> cannot be converted to java.util.Collection<TestApplication.Type<? super C>>`

So: how should `superSuperTypes` be declared in order to be able to assign to it the result of `superType.getSuperTypes()` and then pass it to `superTypes.addAll()` ?

Comment: Just to be a pedant, in Java, braces (`{`) are typically put on the same line as the statement they go with (if statements, function/class declaration, etc.). It makes no difference compile-time and is just as readable, but [hey, Oracle says so](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf#G3.182).

Comment: @QPaysTaxes You don't *seriously* want to start a discussion about code style, do you? And the lack of egyptian brackets is not the only deviation of my style from Oracle's dogma, is it?

Comment: I get a feeling you saw the first sentence and immediately assumed I was some sort of asshole. Feel free to read the whole thing. Strictly speaking, you also shouldn't have spaces between the parentheses and their innards, but I didn't see that at the time. I never said I wanted to discuss it; I was just pointing out a breach of the official Java MoS.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes 
 
I am experienced enough and benevolent-by-default enough to never assume things about people based on things as innocent as SO comments, so you should not have gotten that feeling. I do, however, come across as somewhat belligerent in my comments, without intending to, and this does not impel people to extend the same courtesy to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like so

```
Collection<? extends Type<? super C>> superSuperTypes = mySuperType.getSuperTypes();
```